# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

there is a Web API service that I am developing in **.NET (.net6)**. I use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` package to version this API service. I made developments with this package on my local site without any problems, and I was able to build and run it.

Afterwards, I published this project and added it to `IIS` on my server. But after I installed it in IIS, I got the app result failed error. Thereupon, when I went to my project folder on the server and ran the dll file with the dotnet command, I received the following error:

`Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' at Program.<Main>$(String[] args)`

After making a few attempts, I cached the relevant package with the `gacutil`command. Even though I see the relevant package folder under the assembly folder, I continue to get the same error.

**NOTE:** Upon the error I received, I tried using the
`Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer` 
package for versioning in the project. But I encountered the same error again.

Successful operation of the service by correcting the error

Comment: Just copy the dll to the IIS folder?

Comment: @MateusZampol It is already in that folder

Comment: _"But I encountered the same error again."_ - that means you still have a bad assembly-reference in your codebase. Do a full Clean and Rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing here because I lost my account. I solved the problem for me. As I said, what worked locally was not working on my windows server. I tried most things on the internet so far but it wasn't working. When I was updating the service, I was either updating the json files manually or not at all. It was one of the files I did not change in MyAPI.deps.json. Without further ado, let me tell you that this problem was solved after updating the deps.json file. I hope this is a solution for those who get this error.